# Creating effecient next statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, dynamic, combobox

Hi I have a code where I am using the input string length to determine what kind of part it is. I wrote a else/elseif statement but it is extremely jumbled, and now I get a for without next error, then when I ad a next I get a next without for error. Is there a better way to do this?

I addeded next statement and get end without for error

```
Private Sub UserPartNumberInput_AfterUpdate()

    PartNumberToSearch = UserPartNumberInput.Text

    If Me.UFSearchTypeComboBox.Text = SearchTypeList(1) Then
        If UserPartNumberInput.Text = "" Then
        Else
            CommandButton1.Caption = "Search Google"
        End If
    End If
    
    If SearchingForHeader.Caption = "" Or SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Standards" Then 'Show Header If option Is Chosen
    Else
        SearchingForHeader.Visible = True
    End If

    Dim i As Integer

    If Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 11 Then
                     
        If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) = "0" Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Assembly By Serial #"
            Me.Height = 445
        End If
        If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) <> "0" Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Part By Serial #"
            SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 4)
            SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 6, 2)
            PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        End If
    End If                
            
    If Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 10 Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Stadard Assemblies Parts"    
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 3 Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Part # by code"
            SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            Me.Height = 435
            MsgBox StandardPartOptionCount(1)
        For i = 1 To LastRowLCtbl
            If ADCOStandardizedParts(i) = UserPartNumberInput Then
                Standardpartoptionrownum = i
                next   'added next                                                    
                
             MsgBox Standardpartoptionrownum       
    
            ElseIf IsLetter(Mid(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text, 2, 1)) = True Then

                SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Description"
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 7 Then
    
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Assemblies"
        SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 5, 2)
        PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 8 Then
    
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search 6000XXXX's"
        SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            
        Call StandardPartReturn
          
    ElseIf Len(SearchingForHeader.Caption) = 5 Then
          
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search ADCO Purchase Part #"
        Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Google Search"
        Me.CommandButton2.Caption = "Open DataSheet"
        Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "Open Model"
        SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
                
     Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Part Number Format"
         
     End If
end sub
```

Comment: It would help if you would indent your code correctly. That said: Your for loop `For i = 1 To LastRowLCtbl)` needs a matching `Next`-statement (else the compiler does not know where the loop ends)

Comment: Consider using [`Select Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) instead of a bunch of `If Else` statements

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. I have taught myself over the last month or so and am not sure what you mean by indented correctly. I have tried to research correct indentation for vba on the internet and I cannot find any standard way of doing it. is there a specific format that is best?

Comment: Also when I add the next statement after that for loop it says "next statement without for"

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I cannot use select case as there is some letters and some numbers, unless I am misunderstanding what it does

Comment: The `Next` needs to be before the `ElseIf`. Indent all logical structures in your code. So everything in an `If`, `While`, `For`, `With` should be indented. If you nest them each level should be indented past the next upper level of nesting.

Comment: I fixed your indentation, should be clearer where that `Next` needs to be, after the inner `If` `ElseIf` but before the same level `ElseIf` that the `For` is contained in.

Comment: I added the next where I thought it should be after the             If ADCOStandardizedParts(i) = UserPartNumberInput Then
                Standardpartoptionrownum = i

Comment: howerever I get the error next without for. I have tried moving the next around to every spot I could think of and it doesnt work thanks!

Comment: On a general note - there is too much going on here to be all in one event handler - you are updating controls based on values of other items, so you'd need to repeat this logic in the event handlers for those other items...  Best to split out that type of thing into its own method (Eg "UpdateCaption", which could be called from multiple event handlers)

Answer (score 0):

The next should be after `SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Description"`. Logical structures in your code cannot partially overlap, they must be entirely inside or outside other logical structures. Indenting your code helps to quickly visualise this and avoid the problem you are having. The `Next` should line up with the corresponding `For`:

```
Private Sub UserPartNumberInput_AfterUpdate()

    PartNumberToSearch = UserPartNumberInput.Text

    If Me.UFSearchTypeComboBox.Text = SearchTypeList(1) Then
        If UserPartNumberInput.Text = "" Then
        Else
            CommandButton1.Caption = "Search Google"
        End If
    End If
    
    If SearchingForHeader.Caption = "" Or SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Standards" Then 'Show Header If option Is Chosen
    Else
        SearchingForHeader.Visible = True
    End If

    Dim i As Integer

    If Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 11 Then
                     
        If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) = "0" Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Assembly By Serial #"
            Me.Height = 445
        End If
        If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) <> "0" Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Part By Serial #"
            SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 4)
            SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 6, 2)
            PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        End If
    End If                
            
    If Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 10 Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Stadard Assemblies Parts"    
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 3 Then
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Part # by code"
            SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            Me.Height = 435
            MsgBox StandardPartOptionCount(1)
        For i = 1 To LastRowLCtbl
            If ADCOStandardizedParts(i) = UserPartNumberInput Then
                Standardpartoptionrownum = i
                MsgBox Standardpartoptionrownum       
            ElseIf IsLetter(Mid(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text, 2, 1)) = True Then
                SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Description"
            End if
        Next i
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 7 Then
    
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Assemblies"
        SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 5, 2)
        PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
        
    ElseIf Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text) = 8 Then
    
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search 6000XXXX's"
        SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            
        Call StandardPartReturn
          
    ElseIf Len(SearchingForHeader.Caption) = 5 Then
          
        SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search ADCO Purchase Part #"
        Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Google Search"
        Me.CommandButton2.Caption = "Open DataSheet"
        Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "Open Model"
        SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
                
     Else
        MsgBox "Incorrect Part Number Format"
         
     End If
end sub
```

Using `Select Case` (note this is untested and I may not have understood your logic correctly):

```
Private Sub UserPartNumberInput_AfterUpdate()

    PartNumberToSearch = UserPartNumberInput.Text

    If Me.UFSearchTypeComboBox.Text = SearchTypeList(1) Then
        If UserPartNumberInput.Text = "" Then
        Else
            CommandButton1.Caption = "Search Google"
        End If
    End If
    
    If SearchingForHeader.Caption = "" Or SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Standards" Then 'Show Header If option Is Chosen
    Else
        SearchingForHeader.Visible = True
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    Select Case Len(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text)
        Case 11
            If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) = "0" Then
                SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Assembly By Serial #"
                Me.Height = 445
            End If
            If Left((Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)), 1) <> "0" Then
                SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Part By Serial #"
                SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 4)
                SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 6, 2)
                PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
            End If
    
        Case 10
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Stadard Assemblies Parts"    
        
        Case 3
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Part # by code"
            SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            Me.Height = 435
            MsgBox StandardPartOptionCount(1)
            For i = 1 To LastRowLCtbl
                If ADCOStandardizedParts(i) = UserPartNumberInput Then
                    Standardpartoptionrownum = i
                    MsgBox Standardpartoptionrownum       
                ElseIf IsLetter(Mid(Me.UserPartNumberInput.Text, 2, 1)) = True Then
                    SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search By Description"
                End if
            Next i

        Case 7
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search Standard Assemblies"
            SerialNumberCode = Left(PartNumberToSearch, 3)
            SectionNumberCode = Mid(PartNumberToSearch, 5, 2)
            PartNumberCode = Right(PartNumberToSearch, 3)

        Case 8
            SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search 6000XXXX's"
            SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
              
            Call StandardPartReturn

        Case Else
            If Len(SearchingForHeader.Caption) = 5 Then
          
                SearchingForHeader.Caption = "Search ADCO Purchase Part #"
                Me.CommandButton1.Caption = "Google Search"
                Me.CommandButton2.Caption = "Open DataSheet"
                Me.CommandButton3.Caption = "Open Model"
                SerialNumberCode = PartNumberToSearch
            Else
                MsgBox "Incorrect Part Number Format"
            End If
    End Select
end sub
```

Comment: <facepalm> fixed it